# DataGridView retrieve entire row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm using CellClick to open a message box and show the row contents of a single row from a DataGridView in a form. I was stumped in trying to find something more elegant than what I've got so far. I was searching for a way to display the contents of the column header, and the row value, possibly using foreach or a for loop, but no avail. Any recommendations?

```
private void authorDataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (authorDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Author Number: " + authorDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString()
                + "\nAuthor First Name: " + authorDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString()
                + "\nAuthor Last Name: " + authorDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: The DataSource for the DataGridView is populated using this:
    dbcontext.Authors
            .OrderBy(author => author.LastName)
            .ThenBy(author => author.FirstName)
            .Load();

         authorBindingSource.DataSource = dbcontext.Authors.Local;

Comment: Author is the table name. It will compile if I remove (Author) and add .ToString(), but it only shows the DataGridViewRow index of the selected cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a reference to the row, which simplifies it a bit.

```
DataGridViewRow authorRow = authorDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
if (authorRow.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Author Number: " + authorRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()
            + "\nAuthor First Name: " + authorRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString()
            + "\nAuthor Last Name: " + authorRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
}
```

If you want the Column Header text, I think its:

```
DataGridViewColumn col = authorDataGridView.Column[e.ColumnIndex]
```

and then you can get the header text from:

```
col.HeaderText;
```

If you're going to do something like this a lot, you could encapsulate what you want in a function:

```
    public string ParseRowText(DataGridView grid, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = grid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        string output = "";
        for (int col = 0; col < grid.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            //Get column header and cell contents
            output = output + grid.Columns[col].HeaderText + ": " + row.Cells[col].Value.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Is that the sort of thing you're after, where the Column Headers are "Author Number", "Author First Name", "Author Last Name" etc?

You'd then call it via:

```
private void authorDataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ParseRowText(this, e));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a Show method in the Model-Class of the Objects you are Displaying in your Dgv:

```
public class Author
{
  public int Number { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }

  public void Show()
  {
    MessageBox.Show($"Author Number: {Number}\nAuthor First Name: {FirstName}\nAuthor Last Name: {LastName}");
  }
```

This way you can easily call it in your CellClick-Method

```
private void authorDataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  var author = ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundObject
  //now you have an author-type object and just call your show method
  author.Show()
}
```

as far as you get your items into the Dgv by using the DataSource prop, you can always get them back again with the DataBoundObject Property.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using a BindingSource, you can also achieve this using the BindingSource.Current property - in fact I prefer this because you'll be able to access the current selected Row in the DataGridView from any other event/method (for example a button click as well).

```
private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentAuthor = (Author)authorBindingSource.Current;
    MessageBox.Show(currentAuthor.Name);
}
```

Also to show Author's properties in desired format you could override the ToString() method and then just do a MessageBox.Show(currentAuthor.ToString()).

```
public class Author
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Author Number: {Number}\nAuthor First Name: {FirstName}\nAuthor Last Name: {LastName}";
    }
}
```

Refer to this MSDN help for more info [BindingSource.Current](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.current(v=vs.110).aspx)